# How to make a copy of a procedure in Scheme?

Tags: list, scheme

So, from the **SICP** we know that the `cons` `car` and `cdr` can be defined as a procedure:

```
(define (cons x y)
    (lambda (m) (m x y)))

(define (car z)
    (z (lambda (p q) p)))

(define (cdr z)
    (z (lambda (p q) q)))
```

But the pre-defined procedure `list`, which takes the arguments to build a list, uses the original `cons`. That means, a list that `list` built, isn't a procedure as I want.

```
(car (list 1 2 3))
;The Object (1 2 3) is not applicable
```

So i write this:

```
(define (list . l)
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        (cons (original-car l)
              (list (original-cdr l)))))
```

I just wondering how to define the `original-car` and `original-cdr`. Are there some way to make a copy of a procedure in Scheme? Or there's some alternate way to solve this problem. thx

Comment: `(define original-car car)`? I don't think I get what you're trying to do. I use chicken scheme and `(car '( 1 2 3))` works fine, as does `(car (list 1 2 3))`.

Comment: @cmt it'll work fine in any scheme

Comment: @cmt not works as i want. I just want to define a `list` procedure to adapt my lambda-version cons and car/cdr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to save a reference to the "original" procedures before redefining them, simply create an alias before defining the "new" procedures (I guess that's what you mean by "copying" them). Like this:

```
(define original-cons cons)
(define original-car car)
(define original-cdr cdr)
(define original-list list)
```

In this way, the old procedures can still be used, as long as we refer to them by their new names. In other words, the implementation of `cons`, `car`, `cdr` and `list` as procedures will look like this:

```
(define (my-cons x y)
  (lambda (m) (m x y)))

(define (my-car z)
  (z (lambda (p q) p)))

(define (my-cdr z)
  (z (lambda (p q) q)))

(define (my-list . els)
  (if (null? els)
      '()
      (my-cons
       (original-car els)
       (apply my-list (original-cdr els)))))
```

And sure enough, it works:

```
(define lst (my-list 1 2 3 4))
lst
=> #<procedure>
(my-car lst)
=> 1
(my-car (my-cdr lst))
=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

List in an implementation is defined as

```
(define (list . l) l)
```

However, this is using a lot of the underlying implementation. E.g. to work it uses the native cons. `cons` as defined in `SICP` is a thought experiment so you're implementation needs a little correction:

```
(define (my-cons x y)
    (lambda (m) (m x y)))

(define (my-car z)
    (z (lambda (p q) p)))

(define (my-cdr z)
    (z (lambda (p q) q)))

(define (my-list . l)
  (define (my-list-aux l)
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        (my-cons (car l)
                 (my-list-aux (cdr l)))))
  (my-list-aux l))

;; optional, update binding
(define car my-car)
(define cdr my-cdr)
(define list my-list)
```

my-cons my-car, my-cdr and my-list are as defined in your question. Only change is reference to correct procedure (with name not conflicting with Scheme)

Comment: For some reason I **HAVE TO** overload the default procedure `car` `cdr` and `cons`. That is my biggest problem. And another problem is that my procedure `my-list` should be `(my-list  . l)` (otherwise `(my-list 1 2 3)` raise a Argument Error) but if you defined as `. l`, the l is a list that constructed by original `cons`, not my lambda version. So i just want to make a copy of the original `car` and `cdr` to get out the object.

Comment: Sylwester's answer is correct. Use his implementation of `my-list`. Just create another function called `list` that does `(define (list . l) (my-list (car l)))`

Comment: @cmt Actually. It wasn't quite right. I have updated my answer. You may do what you do in your question and change their names after their are defined like this `(define car my-car)` and this will not alter what is called in the definition since the procedures has it's lexical environment.